# Weird behaivour getting value from merged cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've come across this behaivour in Excel. Given these cells:

```
        A         B         C         D
   |---------|---------|---------|---------|
 1 | merged cell text  | foo     | bar     |
   |---------|---------|---------|---------|
 2 |         |         |         |         |
   |---------|---------|---------|---------|
```

When **Cell C1 is selected** (`foo`), the following VBA statement returns *an empty string*:

```
Debug.Print Selection.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Value
```

This next VBA however returns the expected value (`merged cell text`):

```
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
Debug.Print Selection.Range("A1").Value
```

I can't for the life of my figure out *why* - surely as `Offset` returns a `Range` and `Selection` is also a `Range`, it's just breaking down the same behaivour over multiple lines, and getting different results. The behaivour does not occur when there are no merged cells.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Cell B1 still exists and its value can be read (though it is of course empty). However if you select it, because of the merge, you actually select A1:B1 and the value you get is that of A1.

Comment: You can centre text over a range of cells using Format Cells/Alignment/Horizontal/Centre across selection. This means you never have to deal with another merged cell ever again!

Comment: Why can you just use Debug.Print Selection.Offset(0, -1).Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the reason:

```
Debug.Print Selection.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Value
```

Your current selection is C1, offset -1 column gives you B1.  You are trying to print A1's value while selecting B1, thus gives nothing.  Merged cell does not automatically cause both A1 and B1 being selected.
(you can test by printing B1's value instead).  However:

```
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
Debug.Print Selection.Range("A1").Value
```

selects the range B1 first, which when merged, cause it to select both A1 and B1 on a application level, thus able to print A1's value

Hope that's clear to you

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read the value in a1 from anywhere of the mergedcell,

```
Debug.Print Range("anyCellFormMergedRange").cells(1,1).Value  'wich gets the value from the first cell of a bigger range (here A1:B1)
```

or

```
Debug.Print Range("anyCellFormMergedRange").MergeArea(1, 1).value 'wich gets the value from the first cell of a MERGED range (here A1:B1)
'for a small mergedcell like yours, a simple .mergearea(1) works too
```

you can change the range to anything you need (selection, .offset(x,y), activecell ...) wich are also ranges.

if you want to use the whole mergedCells (A1:B1), without using .select :

(from C1)

```
    Debug.Print selection.offset(0,-1).MergeArea.address
```

Also remember that comment, validation data, are also contained in the first cell of the range (A1 here).